# How can I manage IOS Camera Permission in flutter app?

Tags: ios, flutter, permissions, camera

I have an flutter app and there is a problem about the camera permission for IOS platform.

There are 5 buttons in bottomnavigations and middle of them go to the camera screen (inde value 2)

It works well for android platform but there is a problem about IOS.

When I go to the camera icon (index value 2) it shows permission popup its ok.You know there are two options like one of them Don't Allow and another one is Allow.

If I click Allow function works well but if I click the Don't Allow it goes to the appsettings in phone settings.However, when I click on Don't Allow, it should not go to there.

permission part of my code like below and if someone help me I would be very happy ;

```
            if (value == 2 ) {
              PermissionStatus status = await Permission.camera.request();
              if (Platform.isAndroid && status.isGranted) {
                PermissionStatus micro =
                    await Permission.microphone.request();
                if (micro.isGranted) {
                  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
                  AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo =
                      await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
                  if (androidInfo.version.sdkInt >= 33) {
                    PermissionStatus photo =
                        await Permission.photos.request();
                    PermissionStatus video =
                        await Permission.videos.request();
                    if (photo.isGranted == true &&
                        video.isGranted == true) {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => CameraScreen(),
                        ),
                      ).then((value) {
                        BubblyCamera.cameraDispose;
                      });
                    }
                  } else {
                    PermissionStatus status =
                        await Permission.storage.request();
                    if (status.isGranted) {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => CameraScreen(),
                        ),
                      ).then((value) {
                        BubblyCamera.cameraDispose;
                      });
                    }
                  }
              }
            } else {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => CameraScreen(),
                  ),
                ).then((value) {
                  BubblyCamera.cameraDispose;
                });
              }
            }
```

when I click on Don't Allow, it should not go to the appsettings in phone settings

[image]